# Wordpress Gutenberg Block: use wp.data.select in BlockEdit filter HOC

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, higher-order-components, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to extend the `core/image` block by pulling in the media description field and use its contents as an extra attribute. I am currently stuck with getting a Rest API call with `wp.data.select('core').getMedia(id)` inside the BlockEdit filter HOC to work. Whatever I've tried so far ("directly" using `select` like in example code below or a `useSelect` hook it always results in the same error `"TypeError: select(...).getMedia(...) is undefined"`. I am successfully using core block extensions for other functionality as well as many different select calls in other custom blocks. I am importing `select` and `useSelect` from the `wp.data` package and I have set my dependencies in the plugins PHP.

Here's my code (relevant parts):

Top of script

```
const { select, useSelect } = wp.data;
const restrictTo = ['core/image'];
```

BlockEdit HOC – wrapping image block's Edit function

```
const withDescription = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {
    return (props) => {
        const {name, attributes, setAttributes, isSelected} = props;
        if ( isSelected && restrictTo.includes(name) ) {
            const {id} = attributes;
            // id will be available when image is chosen from the inserter
            if (id) {
                /* doesn't work, yields error described above, even with useSelect hook */
                const desc = select('core').getMedia(id).description.raw;
            }
            // 
        }
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit {...props} />
                <Inspector Controls stuff...>
            </Fragment>
        )
    };
}, 'withDescription');
```

Filter

```
addFilter('editor.BlockEdit','vortac/with-description',withDescription);
```

I have already searched for articles and help covering a similar problem and found this from the wordpress.org support forums:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-use-wp-data-select-in-blocklist/

@jorgefilipecosta is referencing a piece of Core code that is actually using `select`in a HOC. It's a different BlockFilter `editor.BlockListBlock though`, but I don't think this should make a difference.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the mistake in my code. Using `select` in the `BlockEdit` filter HOC is not the actual problem, as I assumed when posting the question. The `select` call itself in the form of `const desc = select('core').getMedia(id).description.raw;` is not correct. I suppose it doesn't work because the `select` call yields a promise and until a value is loaded for `.getMedia()` it is not possible to access the field `description`, resulting in the error I originally described in my question. So here's the actual simple solution in my final implementation using the `useSelect` hook (again just the relevant parts):

```
const { select, useSelect } = wp.data;
const restrictTo = [ 'core/image' ];
```

```
const withDescription = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        const { name, attributes, setAttributes, isSelected } = props;
        if ( isSelected && restrictTo.includes( name ) ) {
            const { id } = attributes;
            
            // an image id will be available as soon as an image is chosen from the inserter
            if ( id ) {
                const tmpDesc = useSelect( ( select ) => {
                   return select( 'core' ).getMedia( id );
                }, [ id ] );
                // if a value for tmpDesc is set its raw description will be accessible
                const desc = ( tmpDesc ) ? tmpDesc[ 'description' ][ 'raw' ] : '';
            }
            // 
        }
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit {...props} />
                <Inspector Controls stuff...>
            </Fragment>
        )
    };
}, 'withDescription');
```

```
addFilter('editor.BlockEdit','vortac/with-description',withDescription);
```